# Passing Data Attributes from Anchor Element to jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of share icons and urls that need to open in a popup, ie: facebook, twitter etc.

I have a jQuery popupWindow function that I don't remember where I found, but it takes the following list of settings:

```
$.fn.popupWindow.defaultSettings = {
    centerBrowser:0,
    centerScreen:0,
    height:500,
    left:0,
    location:0,
    menubar:0,
    resizable:0,
    scrollbars:0,
    status:0,
    width:500,
    windowName:null,
    windowURL:null,
    top:0,
    toolbar:0
};
```

So I can simply pass in the height and width and center to get a very nice popup for sharing like so:

```
$(element).popupWindow({ 
    centerBrowser: 1,
    width: 500,
    height: 250 
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't get access to the data-attributes of my link in order to pass in height and width to the popover method.

My links look similar to:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?etc" 
    class="social-share facebook" 
    data-width="550" 
    data-height="275">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Tried:

```
$('.social-share').popupWindow({ 
    centerBrowser: 1,
    height: $(this).attr('data-height'),
    width: $(this).attr('data-width')
});
```

This just ignores the scripting and goes to FB in the same window.

Tried:

```
$('.social-share').popupWindow({ 
    centerBrowser: 1,
    height: this.attr('data-height'),
    width: this.attr('data-width')
});
```

Object has no attribute attr.

Inside the popupWindow function they've written some overrides that choose the element's properties first, then fallback to the settings like so:

```
settings.windowName = this.name || settings.windowName;
settings.windowURL = this.href || settings.windowURL;
```

My thought is that this is the most elegant and functional solution, so that there would be a triple fallback, first see if there's `data-width` and `data-height` attributes, then check the passed in settings, then use the default settings.

But alas, I can't seem to get that to work either.

I tried adding both:

```
settings.width = $(this).attr('data-width') || settings.width;
settings.height = $(this).attr('data-height') || settings.height;
```

this has no effect on height or width, just uses default.

and tried:

```
settings.width = this.attr('data-width') || settings.width;
settings.height = this.attr('data-height') || settings.height;
```

this throws error object has no attribute attr.

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Instead of frequently accessing the DOM, try to do this using **`.data()`**
I guess the problem is you're missing to add **`units`**

```
$('.social-share').popupWindow({ 
    centerBrowser: 1,
    height: this.data('height') + 'px',
    width:  this.data('width') + 'px'
});
```

Comment: object has no attribute data.  plus, the popupWindow function doesn't take units in the settings.